# Forward declaration of function pointer typedef

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef, forward-declaration

I've run into a peculiar problem. It might be best to just show you what I'm trying to do and then explain it.

```
typedef void functionPointerType ( struct_A * sA );

typedef struct
{
    functionPointerType ** functionPointerTable;
}struct_A;
```

Basically, I have a structure `struct_A` with a pointer to a table of function pointers, who have a parameter of type `struct_A`. But I'm not sure how to get this compile, as I'm not sure how or if can forward declare this.

Anyone know how this could be achieved?

edit: minor fix in code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Forward declare as you suggest:

```
/* Forward declare struct A. */
struct A;

/* Typedef for function pointer. */
typedef void (*func_t)(struct A*);

/* Fully define struct A. */
struct A
{
    func_t functionPointerTable[10];
};
```

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A;

typedef void (*func_t)(struct A*);

struct A
{
    func_t functionPointerTable[10];
    int value;
};

void print_stdout(struct A* a)
{
    printf("stdout: %d\n", a->value);
}

void print_stderr(struct A* a)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "stderr: %d\n", a->value);
}

int main()
{
    struct A myA = { {print_stdout, print_stderr}, 4 };

    myA.functionPointerTable[0](&myA);
    myA.functionPointerTable[1](&myA);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
stdout: 4
stderr: 4
```

See online demo http://ideone.com/PX880w .

---

As others have already mentioned it is possible to add:

```
typedef struct A struct_A;
```

prior to the function pointer `typedef` and full definition of `struct A` if it is preferable to omit the `struct` keyword.

Comment: the syntax for this always threw me off.

Comment: "As others have already mentioned" Indeed. You may as well just put it into your answer and then I can delete mine. I think it would make your answer better and it's the one that rose to the top.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, thanks. The example is contrived and the usefulness of the additional `typedef` is not really conveyed (`struct A` or `struct_A`).

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
//forward declaration of the struct
struct _struct_A;                               

//typedef so that we can refer to the struct without the struct keyword
typedef struct _struct_A struct_A;              

//which we do immediately to typedef the function pointer
typedef void functionPointerType(struct_A *sA); 

//and now we can fully define the struct    
struct _struct_A                        
{
    functionPointerType ** functionPointerTable;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another way to do it:

```
typedef struct struct_A_
{
    void  (** functionPointerTable) (struct struct_A_);
}struct_A;


 void typedef functionPointerType ( struct_A );
```